# Trying to match text via REGEX

Tags: regex, tcl

First time posting, and need a little help with a regex match I'm trying to come up with.

Here is the format I have

```
|user|DOMAIN\user|
```

I'm trying to write a regex match that will only capture the username, and then only capture the domain.

My thought process is to first match all the text and then create (3) groups? based on that I would have the information I'm looking for.

Suggestions? Examples?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `\|(user)\|(DOMAIN)\\user\|`

Comment: TCL would be the language

Comment: @router7 Please add the correct language tags in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using non-greedy quantifiers helps a lot in readability here:

```
set data {|glenn|JACKMAN\glenn|}
regexp  {^\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\\} $data -> user domain
puts "$user:$domain"
```

outputs

```
glenn:JACKMAN
```

Comment: If I wanted to break up the user and the domain into separate regex would you happen to provide me with an example?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It will make your code harder to read: `regexp  {^\|(.*?)\|} $data -> user; regexp  {^\|.*?\|(.*?)\\} $data -> domain`

Comment: I'm using it to assign variables for the username and the domain

Comment: My answer does that too.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a regex like this:

```
\|([^|]+)\|([^\]+)\\([^|]+)\|
```

Comment: That looks cool but it looks like it's matching the entire thing highlighted in green what if I wanted to match just user or just domain?

Comment: It matches the whole thing and returns the 3 values as captures -- note the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a constraint to use regex match, I would suggest that you go with splitting the string at pipes. This way, your first or second token (depending on how the given language treats an empty token before first pipe) will be user. Now you can remove the [length(user) + 1] substring from end of the next token. This would provide you with the DOMAIN.

Note that the assumption here is, that user or DOMAIN do not contain any pipe character (|).

Answer (score 0):

This is also another option for matching the username and domain.

% set data {|glenn|JACKMAN\glenn|}

|glenn|JACKMAN\glenn|

% regexp {^\|([^|]+)\|([^\]+).*} $data m a b

1

% puts "--- a $a ----b $b----"

--- a glenn ----b JACKMAN----

Another way for exact match.

% regexp {^\|([A-z]+)\|([A-z]+)\.*} $data m a b

1

% puts "match $m--- a $a ----b $b----"

match |glenn|JACKMAN\glenn|--- a glenn ----b JACKMAN----